# Conventional way of initializing class variables via methods (class methods or methods outside class?)

Tags: python, class

I have 3 different config files from which I would want to initialize different class variables for different major functions

Q1. What is the more conventional way of initializing class variables via methods (class methods or methods outside class)

Q2. How to initialize class variables via class methods

**config.py**

```
class CONFIG:
    x_config = 'x_config.json'
    y_config = 'y_config.json'
    z_config = 'z_config.json'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to set the config values,

```
class CONFIG:
    
    # Class initialisation happens here
    def __init__(self, config_value):
        default_config = 'x_config.json' # Set your default config file
        config_dict = {'x_config': 'x_config.json',
                        'y_config': 'y_config.json',
                        'z_config': 'z_config.json'}
        self.config_file = config_dict.get(config_value, default_config)

# You can pass the default config value to the class
config = CONFIG('y_config')
print(config.config_file)
```

Output:

```
'y_config.json'
```

*Q1. What is the more conventional way of initializing class variables via methods (class methods or methods outside class)*

**ANS**: Via init method `__init__`

*Q2. How to initialize class variables via class methods*

**ANS**:  It's not a best practice to initialize from its methods. You can rewrite the class attribute from the class methods.

```
self.config_file = 'z_config.json'
```

This can call from the class methods.

Comment: in the example you have not prefixed default_config or config_dict with self keyword. I need more understanding on when  should we use an identifier with self

Comment: The self variable will have the scope of the entire class and if you do not prefix with `self` it's only used within the method. So here, `default_config` I won't use in any other methods in the class. If you using this variable in other functions you have to prefix it with `self`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. One more query if I want to access a class from an imported module in the current class should I instantiate within __init__ or before __init__

Comment: It depends on the imported class. The best practice would be inside `init`. It's better you read about [inheritance](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/inheritance) also.

Comment: please look into the below question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088995/updating-class-instance-variables-in-python-using-methods)

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

The most conventional way would be to initialize them in the `__init__` method of the class.

## Option 2

You can initialize class variables in class methods by using the self keyword. For example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def class_method(self):
        self.var1 = 3
        self.var2 = 4
```

Comment: Hi but I don't want to call the class_method every time in other modules while I import 'config.py' to get the latest value of self.var2

Comment: @rams Can you clarify your use case, and when/why/how often you need to initialize attributes outside of `__init__`?