# Updating class / instance variables in Python using methods

Tags: python, class, methods

I have different set of config files initialized under a **Config class** and would need them updated dynamically in the run time.

***config.py***

```
# Package import
import reusable.common as common
import reusable.JSON_utils as JSON


class Config:
def __init__(self):
    # run_config
    run_file = common.file_path('run_config.JSON')
    self.run_dict = JSON.read(run_file)
    self.env_list = list(self.run_dict.keys())

    # connection_config
    self.conn_file = common.file_path('connection_config.JSON')
    self.conn_dict = JSON.read(self.conn_file)

    # snapshot_config
    self.snap_file = common.file_path('snapshot_config.JSON')
    self.snap_dict = JSON.read(self.snap_file)
```

For example I have to iterate through different environments like (DEV, STAGE, QA, PROD) and want to update conn_dict('env') to 'QA' from 'DEV' after DEV tasks are completed. Currently I have the update dict/JSON code in main() but I want to have this **as a method inside the Config class**

```
# Package import
import reusable.config as config
import reusable.JSON_utils as JSON

config_obj = config.Config() 

for env in config_obj.env_list:
    config_obj.conn_dict['env'] = env
    JSON.write(config_obj.conn_dict, config_obj.conn_file)
    src_id_list = config_obj.run_dict.get(env).get('snapshot')
    # do stuff in the current env 

for src_id in src_id_list:
    config_obj.snap_dict['source_id'] = str(src_id)
    JSON.write(config_obj.snap_dict, config_obj.snap_file)
    # do stuff for the current data source
```

**Q1** Which method is the optimal and conventional way for this. Class or instant or static method? kindly explain as I'm not clear with those completely

**Q2** Can we have a unified method inside the class that takes the dict variable and function as parameters to update the dict and JSON file. If yes how it can be achieved?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? The way Stack Overflow is optimized for narrow, nuts-and-bolts, factual questions, it can be hard to get good answers here about best practices for laying out your program's structure, since that's more of a big-picture design decision. You might be able to find some insight from [similar questions there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+config), and/or ask your own with more luck there than here.